# How to displaying a map in struts 2

Tags: jsp, dictionary, struts2

I have a map `

> {
>   key1=[button1,button2,button3,button4],key2=[button1],key3=[button1,button2],key4=[button1,button2,button3]}

` i want to display this map contents in my jsp like below[image]

How to do this in struts 2 tags.... Please help me to solve this issue.... Thanks In advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will iterate over your map and every element in the arrays of the values of the map.

```
<s:iterator value="map">
    <s:property value="key"/>
    <s:iterator value="value">
        <s:property/>
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```